# Proof that $(A^t)^t=A$, $(A+B)^t=A^t+B^t$, $(AB)^t=B^tA^t$, and deduce that $BB^t$ is symmetric and $B-B^t$ is skew-symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, transpose, skew-symmetric-matrices

In a linear algebra textbook, I was given the following problem:

> If $B$ is a $n \times n$ square matrix, show that $BB^t$ is symmetric and $B-B^t$ is skew-symmetric.

---

I know that there are relatively quick solutions using elementary matrix arithmetic. But I came up with a different way and wanted to ask if this is correct. Thereby I hope it is accepted to post two problems/solutions into one post, since these are quite connected. If not, please correct me.

To show that $BB^t$ is symmetric, let $A=BB^t$. I denote entries by $a$, $b$ and $b^t$ and show that $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$ for every entry of $A$. By the definition of matrix multiplication $a_{ij}=\sum_{k=0}^n b_{ik}b^t_{kj}$. But $b_{ik}=b^t_{ki}$ and $b^t_{kj}=b_{jk}$ by matrix transposition. So we have $$a_{ij}=\sum_{k=0}^n b_{ik}b^t_{kj}=\sum_{k=0}^n b_{jk}b^t_{ki}=a_{ji}$$ as required.

To show that $B-B^t$ is skew-symmetric, let $A=B-B^t$. We show that $a_{ij}=-a_{ji}$ for every entry of $A$. By definition of a difference of matrices $a_{ij}=b_{ij}-b^t_{ij}$. But $b_{ij}=b^t_{ji}$ and $b^t_{ij}=b_{ji}$ by matrix transposition. So we have

$$a_{ij}=b_{ij}-b^t_{ij}=b^t_{ji}-b_{ji}=-b_{ji}+b^t_{ji}=-(b_{ji}-b^t_{ji})=-a_{ji}$$

which completes our proof.

Comment: Your solution is fine but, as you said, it is much more complicated than the immediate one.

Comment: You should really be aware that your solution amounts to explicitly proving the relevant special cases of the relevant facts of elementary matrix arithmetic. That said, it’s an excellent habit to think about alternative proofs to results you encounter, and to really think critically about proofs you encounter and how they work.

Comment: To expand on Branimir Ćaćić's comment, The "quick way" is to make use of the matrix arithmetic formulas $$(BC)^T = C^TB^T\\(B - C)^T = B^T - C^T\\(B^T)^T = B$$ But these are not axioms. They themselves have to be proved, and what you have provided are exactly those proofs for the case $C=B^T$.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, #Branimir Ćaćić and #Paul Sinclair. I‘ll expand on them and try to proof the general formulas in a new post. I think, this would be OT here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following, I try to use the comments of @Branimir Ćaćić and @Paul Sinclair to expand my original solution by proofing some general rules of matrix arithmetic and deducing the results on symmetry and skew-symmetry from them.

**Proposition**: Let $A$ and $B$ be two matrices, whose size allows the following operations. Then

$$ \begin{align} &A) & (A^t)^t &= A \\
&B) & (A+B)^t &= A^t+B^t \\
&C) & (AB)^t &= B^tA^t \end{align}$$

**Proof**: For the first proposition notice that $a_{ij}=a_{ji}^t$ for every entry in $A$ and $A^t$ respectively. Transposing $A^T$ again yields $a_{ji}^t=a_{ij}$ as required.

To proof $B)$ let $A + B = C$ and $A^t + B^t = D$. We show that $c_{ji}^t = d_{ij}$ for every $c_{ji}^t$ and $d_{ij}$ in $C^t$ or $D$, respectively. Now, $c_{ji}^t = c_{ij} = a_{ij} + b_{ij}$ and $d_{ij} = a_{ji}^t + b_{ji}^t$ by definition of a sum of matrices. Since we also have $a_{ij} = a_{ji}^t$ as well as $b_{ij} = b_{ji}^t$ due to transposition of a matrix, we get

$$c_{ji}^t = c_{ij} = a_{ij}+b_{ij} = a_{ji}^t+b_{ji}^t = d_{ij}$$

which completes the proof.

For the proof of $C)$ let $A B = C$ and $A^t B^t = D$. Similar to the previous argument we will show that $c_{ji}^t = d_{ij}$ for every $c_{ji}^t$ and $d_{ij}$ in $C^t$ or $D$. Notice that $c_{ji}^t = c_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik} b_{kj}$ and $d_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n b_{jk}^t a_{ki}^t$, due to matrix multiplication. Since by matrix transposition we also have $a_{ik} = a_{ki}^t$ as well as $b_{kj} = b_{jk}^t$ we come to the conclusion that

$$c_{ji}^t = c_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik} b_{kj} = \sum_{k=1}^n b_{jk}^t a_{ki}^t = d_{ij}$$

as required.

**Corollary**: Per definition, a matrix is symmetric, if for any matrix $B^t=B$ and skew-symmetric if $B^t=-B$. We now can immediately deduce, by $A)$ and $C)$, that

$$(B B^t)^t=(B^t)^t B^t = B B^t$$

which shows, that $BB^t$ is symmetric and, using $B)$, that

$$(B - B^t)^t = B^t - (B^t)^t =  B^t - B = - (B - B^t)$$

so $B - B^t$ is skew-symmetric. $\blacksquare$